# Validate composite key within array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

For validating phone numbers in my application I need to combine it with a country id to make sure the combination is unique not the phone number itself. This has not been a problem in the past and has been solved using the following method in validation classes

```
   'phone' => ['required', 'string',
            Rule::unique('users')
                ->where('country_id', $this->country_id)
                ->where('phone', $this->phone)
        ],
```

However I am now accepting an arrray of users and the following rule does not seem to work

```
  'contacts.*.phone' => ['required', 'string',
            Rule::unique('users')
                ->where('country_id', $this->country_id)
                ->where('phone', $this->phone)
        ],
```

Have not found anything on stack overflow or within the documentation for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`Rule::forEach`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#accessing-nested-array-data), in your use case it might look like the following:

```
'contacts.*.phone' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    Rule::forEach(function ($value, $attribute) {
        return [
            Rule::unique('users')
                ->where('country_id', $value)
                ->where('phone', $value),
        ];
    }),
],
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the error I get back "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Rule::forEach does not exist." Have tried it both "foreach" and "forEach" I should mention this is inside a request class

Comment: @meowzart I assume you have added `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` at the top of your `Request` class?

Comment: Yes I have, The unique Rule was not throwing any errors

Comment: @meowzart I've just noticed you're using `Laravel 8` and that's a `Laravel 9` rule. In which case you'll likely need to create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: will also be interesting since by default I only have access to the phone number not the country_id in the rule class